# How can we change Managed Replica to Standard Replica and vice versa using scripting in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I want to create users mail file as Managed Replica and users will change the mail file from Managed Replica to Standard Replica and Vice Versa according to their availability. Do any one have idea how to accomplish this task?

Comment: I doubt that this is possible. Users would likely have to have administrative rights on the server in order to create/disable management replicas.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz you can make request/approval mechanism behind it, and agent with administrative rights to process it.

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth Yes, if it is handled by AdminP, I suppose that would work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need a pre-step. You could put your users in as Designers instead of Managers in the ACL. This will keep your users from making changes. You can also force other rules with the ACL of a database. You can write scripts to make these changes on a server by server basis or even by folder. Normally Executives are given full access so they might be in a different folder.

I don't understand what you mean by availability. You can enforce rules for encryption and such on a remote replica.

You might have two different concepts here. Are you talking remote side or server side? The remote replication might change settings on your server side replica if you keep people at the Manager level.

I would also look at rule policies and see if something there will work as well.